# How to account for 0 and 0.00

Tags: javascript

Have a simple script in place that works well but doesn't account for all forms of 0 (0.0, 0.00..etc) What is the simplest way to achieve this? Maybe parseFloat?

```
if(value !== "0") {
 alert('No sir this cant be empty');
 return false;
}
```

if they put in 0 in the textbox it will return false fine. However, if they put 0.0 it will return true

Comment: > 'Maybe parseFloat?'
Sounds like you're answering your own question, there :)

Comment: You've already answered your question. Use `parseFloat`. =)

Comment: Why don't you try `parseFloat` and see what happens?

Comment: parseFloat wasn't working for me but with some of these suggestions that might work thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4):

You could use `parseFloat` and compare against `0`

```
if (parseFloat(value) !== 0) {
    // complain
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can parseFloat it but you shouldn't need to use quotes around your value.

```
value !== 0
```

Comment: *If* using `!=` (and not `!==`) this solution will actually work because the value will be converted numerically first .. (this can be verified with `"0.0" == 0"` and `"1.1" == 1.1`).

Answer (score 1):

Parse it into an actual number first, similar to this:

```
value = parseFloat(value)

if( value === 0 ) return false;
```

You'll want to look into `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might try a regular expression match?

```
if (value.match(/^0(?:\.0+)?$/)) {
    alert("hey!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `parseInt`, seems to be the simplest:

```
if(parseInt(value, 10) != 0) {
 alert('No sir this cant be empty');
 return false;
}
```

But be sure you test `value` against `undefined`, `null` and empty string before that.